# How to update lsp-java manually?

Tags: java, lsp-mode

I'm trying to run a simple HelloWorld from Emacs using dap-mode commands `dap-debug` and `dap-java-debug` but prompted the error saying

```
lsp-request: No delegateCommandHandler for vscode.java.resolveMainClass
```

So I try to update the language server to see if it helps (see this [issue](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/dap-mode/issues/65)) by running

```
M-x lsp-java-update-server
```

Then I'm stuck in the process of downloading the `jdt-language-server-latest.tar.gz` package and eventually the updating fails due to downloading timeout. So I manually download the package from [the address](https://download.eclipse.org/jdtls/snapshots/jdt-language-server-latest.tar.gz) as shown in the updating log and put it under my `lsp-java-server-install-dir` which is `~/.emacs.d/eclipse.jdt.ls/server/` and then run `lsp-java-update-server` again. Still it attempts to download the package and is stuck there. Is it possible to skip the downloading step and continue to the following steps? Also I have installed lsp-java successfully in the same way and features like real-time diagnostics (via flymake) and code completion (via company-lsp) all work fine. So I suppose the language server should be the latest version but something is still missing such as some dependencies it would require since I installed it manually. I also tried to find a clue from the source code of `lsp-java-update-server` but I'm new to elisp so didn't really find anything helpful.

My init file:

```
;; Bad request problem 
(setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3")

;; Added by Package.el.  This must come before configurations of
;; installed packages.  Don't delete this line.  If you don't want it,
;; just comment it out by adding a semicolon to the start of the line.
;; You may delete these explanatory comments.
(package-initialize)

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(ace-window-display-mode nil)
 '(ansi-color-faces-vector
   [default default default italic underline success warning error])
 '(aw-background nil)
 '(blink-matching-paren t)
 '(browse-url-browser-function (quote browse-url-chrome))
 '(column-number-mode t nil nil "Show column number")
 '(company-show-numbers t)
 '(custom-safe-themes
   (quote
    ("a24c5b3c12d147da6cef80938dca1223b7c7f70f2f382b26308eba014dc4833a" "624f3b1e86a81d1873b93edc3cce0947f2042bfeebecc480b393ff1e0aa4abfd" default)))
 '(electric-pair-mode t)
 '(hl-sexp-background-color "#1c1f26")
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t nil nil "Hide welcome screen")
 '(lsp-java-format-settings-profile "GoogleStyle")
 '(lsp-java-format-settings-url "~/Downloads/eclipse-java-google-style.xml")
 '(minibuffer-eldef-shorten-default t)
 '(minibuffer-electric-default-mode t)
 '(mode-require-final-newline nil)
 '(org-replace-disputed-keys t)
 '(package-check-signature (quote allow-unsigned))
 '(package-selected-packages
   (quote
    (dap-mode lsp-ui company-lsp use-package yasnippet lsp-java gnu-elpa-keyring-update nov magit projectile)))
 '(set-mark-command-repeat-pop t)
 '(show-paren-mode t)
 '(tab-width 4)
 '(tool-bar-mode nil)
 '(tool-bar-position (quote top))
 '(tooltip-mode nil))

(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

(put 'downcase-region 'disabled nil)
(put 'upcase-region 'disabled nil)

;; === Custom keybindings
(global-set-key (kbd "<S-return>") 'newline-below-without-break)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-S-return>") 'newline-above-without-break)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-]") 'xah-forward-block)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-[") 'xah-backward-block)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-tab>") 'other-window)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-iso-lefttab>") 'prev-window)
(global-set-key (kbd "<M-S-backspace>") 'previous-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-M-backspace>") 'next-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "<M-f2>") 'browse-url-of-file)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-o") 'ace-window)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-f5>") 'lsp-format-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-S-f5>") 'lsp-format-region)
(global-set-key [(meta shift ?s)] 'lsp-find-references)
;; (global-set-key [?\M-\S-s] 'lsp-find-references)
;; (global-set-key (kbd "M-S-s") 'lsp-find-references)
;; (global-set-key (kbd "<M-shift-s>") 'lsp-find-references)
(global-set-key (kbd "C->") 'lsp-goto-implementation)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<") 'lsp-java-open-super-implementation)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-h") 'lsp-ui-find-next-reference)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-H") 'lsp-ui-find-prev-reference)

;; Open new line below current line without breaking current line
(defun newline-below-without-break ()
  "1.Move to end of line; 2. Insert newline with index"
  (interactive)
  (let ((oldpos (point))) (end-of-line) (newline-and-indent)))

;; Open new line above current line without breaking current line
(defun newline-above-without-break ()
  "Insert an empty line above the currentline. Position the cursor at its beginning, according the current mode"
  (interactive)
  (move-beginning-of-line nil)
  (newline-and-indent)
  (forward-line -1)
  (indent-according-to-mode))

;; Move to next blank line separated block
(defun xah-forward-block (&optional n)
  "Move cursor beginning of next text block.
A text block is separated by blank lines.
This command similar to `forward-paragraph', but this command's behavior is the same regardless of syntax table.
URL `http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_move_by_paragraph.html'
Version 2016-06-15"
  (interactive "p")
  (let ((n (if (null n) 1 n)))
    (re-search-forward "\n[\t\n ]*\n+" nil "NOERROR" n)))

;; Move to previous blank line separated block
(defun xah-backward-block (&optional n)
  "Move cursor to previous text block.
See: `xah-forward-block'
URL `http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_move_by_paragraph.html'
Version 2016-06-15"
  (interactive "p")
  (let ((n (if (null n) 1 n))
        ($i 1))
    (while (<= $i n)
      (if (re-search-backward "\n[\t\n ]*\n+" nil "NOERROR")
          (progn (skip-chars-backward "\n\t "))
        (progn (goto-char (point-min))
               (setq $i n)))
      (setq $i (1+ $i)))))

(defun prev-window () (interactive) (other-window -1))

;; === Theme
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/")
(load-theme 'zenburn t t)
(enable-theme 'zenburn)

;; === Packages
(require 'package)
(let* ((no-ssl (and (memq system-type '(windows-nt ms-dos))
                    (not (gnutls-available-p))))
       (proto (if no-ssl "http" "https")))
  (when no-ssl
    (warn "\
Your version of Emacs does not support SSL connections,
which is unsafe because it allows man-in-the-middle attacks.
There are two things you can do about this warning:
1. Install an Emacs version that does support SSL and be safe.
2. Remove this warning from your init file so you won't see it again."))
  ;; Comment/uncomment these two lines to enable/disable MELPA and MELPA Stable as desired
  (add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa" (concat proto "://melpa.org/packages/")) t)
  ;;(add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa-stable" (concat proto "://stable.melpa.org/packages/")) t)
  (when (< emacs-major-version 24)
    ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
    (add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "gnu" (concat proto "://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))))
(package-initialize)

(require 'projectile)
(define-key projectile-mode-map (kbd "M-p") 'projectile-command-map)
(projectile-mode +1)

;; === VCS
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x g") 'magit-status)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c g") 'magit-file-dispatch)


(require 'lsp-java)
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook #'lsp)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)

(require 'cc-mode)

(condition-case nil
    (require 'use-package)
  (file-error
   (require 'package)
   (add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
   (package-initialize)
   (package-refresh-contents)
   (package-install 'use-package)
   (require 'use-package)))

(use-package projectile :ensure t)
(use-package yasnippet :ensure t)
(use-package lsp-mode :ensure t)
(use-package hydra :ensure t)
(use-package company-lsp :ensure t)
(use-package lsp-ui :ensure t)
(use-package lsp-java :ensure t :after lsp
  :config (add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'lsp))

(use-package dap-mode
  :ensure t :after lsp-mode
  :config
  (dap-mode t)
  (dap-ui-mode t))

(use-package dap-java :after (lsp-java))


(with-eval-after-load 'org       
  (setq org-startup-indented t) ; Enable `org-indent-mode' by default
  (add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'visual-line-mode))

(setq find-function-C-source-directory "~/Projects/emacs-26.2/src/")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ATM there are no manual instructions, please open an issue in lsp-java repo. To fix your problem do:

1. M-x lsp-java-update-server - do that to force lsp-java to download the install pom.xml and cancel the task.
2. In the *Messages* buffer there will be something like this:

```
Wrote /tmp/lsp-java-install4rWMay/pom.xml
/usr/bin/mvn -Djdt.js.server.root=/home/kyoncho/.emacs.d/eclipse.jdt.ls/server/ -Djunit.runner.root=/home/kyoncho/.emacs.d/eclipse.jdt.ls/test-runner/ -Djunit.runner.fileName=junit-platform-console-standalone.jar -Djava.debug.root=/home/kyoncho/.emacs.d/eclipse.jdt.ls/server/bundles clean package -Djdt.download.url=https://download.eclipse.org/jdtls/snapshots/jdt-language-server-latest.tar.gz: exited abnormally with code 130.
```

3. Go into `/tmp/lsp-java-install4rWMay/` directory and edit pom.xml to remove the download language server task:

```
          <execution>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <id>download-che</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>wget</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <url>${jdt.download.url}</url>
              <outputFileName>jdt-language-server-latest.tar.gz</outputFileName>
              <skipCache>true</skipCache>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
```

and

```
                <untar src="${project.build.directory}/jdt-language-server-latest.tar.gz" compression="gzip" dest="${jdt.js.server.root}" />
```

4. Rerun the failing command in the temp directory:

```
/usr/bin/mvn -Djdt.js.server.root=/home/kyoncho/.emacs.d/eclipse.jdt.ls/server/ -Djunit.runner.root=/home/kyoncho/.emacs.d/eclipse.jdt.ls/test-runner/ -Djunit.runner.fileName=junit-platform-console-standalone.jar -Djava.debug.root=/home/kyoncho/.emacs.d/eclipse.jdt.ls/server/bundles clean package -Djdt.download.url=https://download.eclipse.org/jdtls/snapshots/jdt-language-server-latest.tar.gz
```